# Can't use a macro as argument to a tabular if it's not used in the first column

Tags: tables, macros, arguments

I have a more complex problem than the MWE I provide. The example, however, points directly to my issue.

I have a macro to do some processing (like `\specialline` in the MWE) and pass it to another macro, which is responsible to produce the line of the itself (`\tableline`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{sum}
\newcommand{\tableline}[3]{%
    \addtocounter{sum}{#3}%
    #1 & #2 & #3 \\
}

\newcommand{\specialline}[1][]{%
    \def\myinput{#1}%
    \ifx\myinput\empty%
        \def\mytext{---}%
    \else%
        \def\mytext{\textit{\myinput}}%
    \fi%
    \tableline{\mytext}{}{100} %%% this works
    %\tableline{}{\mytext}{100} %%% this fails
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
    \tableline{X}{Y}{10}
    \tableline{M}{L}{40}
    \tableline{K}{T}{50}
    \specialline
    \specialline[something]
    \hline
    & & \thesum \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If the macro `\mytext` goes to the first column, everything goes fine. But in any other column the compilation fails. Here's the log:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mytext 
                   
l.29        \specialline
                   [something]
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The actual `\tableline` and `\specialline` I use are more complex and involves several other macros along with writing to a temporary file. So replicate part of the code of `\tableline` in `\specialline` is not desirable, since maintenance will suffer.

My question: why does it fails to compile and how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: This comment does not answer the question but does provide a hint on good practices: `\newcommand{\specialline}[1][]{\def\myinput{#1}%...}` loads to error-messages with things like `\specialline{A#1B}`. If you have to define a macro from an arbitrary macro-argument, do `\newcommand{\specialline}[1][]{\myscratchtoks{#1}\edef\myinput{\the\myscratchtoks}%...}`, `\myscratchtoks` being a token-register, or `\newcommand{\specialline}[1][]{\edef\myinput{\unexpanded{#1}}%...}` This way hash-tokens in `#1` are doubled in the definition of `\myinput`. They are halved when expanding `\myinput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table cells act as groups, meaning that the macros `\myinput` and `\mytext` are defined in the first cell of the row and exist only there. One possible solution would be to replace `\def` by `\gdef` but I'd rather avoid the complicated construction with helper macros and put the code directly in the second argument of `\tableline`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{sum}

\newcommand{\tableline}[3]{%
    \addtocounter{sum}{#3}%
    #1 & #2 & #3 \\
}

\newcommand{\specialline}[1][]{%
    \tableline{}{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax---\else\textit{#1}\fi}{100}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
    \tableline{X}{Y}{10}
    \tableline{M}{L}{40}
    \tableline{K}{T}{50}
    \specialline
    \specialline[something]
    \hline
    & & \thesum
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I have used a somewhat safer test for emptyness..

Comment: I got the point of using `gdef`, but as it's a very local use of temporary values, I'll go with including the definitions within the arguments. It will certainly look strange, because some of the arguments will be really long. Appreciate your answer!